# Spring mvc doesn't see jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm creating a Spring MVC application and can't figure out why I get 404 error when launch my application. I want to see welcome page but it doesn't show. What is the issue?

In /WEB-INF/view there is index.jsp file with simple Hello text.

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
       version="3.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>grun</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/grun-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>grun</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

grun-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="Controller"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class AController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Comment: Which URL do you try to reach?

Comment: tried localhost:8080 and localhost:8080/grun/

Comment: What is your web-app context path? What do your servlet container's logs say?

Comment: context path is '/' and there doesn't seem to be any errors.

Comment: No errors, fine. But do you see your controller being registered?

Comment: Hmm, I guess not. It didn't stop on breakpoint in return statement.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is it necessary to add ContextLoaderListener?

Comment: No, it is not in this case. Show us where you set your context path. And show us your directory structure just so we're sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56487/discussion-between-qiguar-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Comment: First put syso in your method to confirm if you are reaching to correct url. See console to check if controller for your request is resolved or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this below bit in grun-servlet.xml

```
base-package="Controller"
```

Unusual to name a package as Controller with the uppercase 'C'. So unless you have

```
package Controller;
```

at the beginning of your AController.java file, that is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following

`WEB-INF` flolder in generally where runtime libraries and class go. Create `view` folder inside `Webcontent` folder and provide path as

```
<property name="prefix" value="/view/"/>
```

`Wecontent` is your root folder for all the resources you want to expose. Reason was doing above is that as Webcontent is the root folder to expose web resources directories inside it can be specified relative to this. So Any resource `abc` under folder `xyz` can be accessed using `/abc/xyz`.

Comment: Still nothing. May be there is something missing or I should register view folder to have access to it?

Comment: You flipped 180 on your answer (you're still wrong), but you haven't given a reason why either should work.

Comment: This is the configuration I use in all my projects. To refer to the jsp pages directly(or do GET/POST request) I use complete URL `http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/view/welcome.jsp`.

Comment: They aren't going to the JSP directly. They are trying to reach it through a Controller. (Please reply with my id.)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your configuration, Just add Index.jsp as a welcome file on you web.xml and it should works

```
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your web.xml to this

```
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>grun</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>grun</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/grun-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


 Hope it will work fine
```

Answer (score -1):

2 possible things:

Did you try putting the request mapping at the method level instead of at the Controller level?

```
@Controller
public class AController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Try adding the below to your grun-servlet.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.yyy" />
```

where "com.xxx.yyy" is the base package to which your AController belongs to.

Comment: `annotation-config` is redundant with `component-scan`. Don't you think `Controller` is their package?

Comment: Also, `@RequestMapping` can be used at the class level just fine.